# How to implement List<T,T>?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of objects:

```
  MyDisplayObjects = new List<ISave> { Patient, ServiceBilling, ReferredBy, POA, PrimaryInsurance, SecondaryInsurance };
```

Where each  object inherits from ISave so that

```
foreach (var o in MyDisplayObjects)
 {
  o.CanSaveEvent += new EventHandler<CanSaveEventArgs>(CanSaveEventHandler);
 }
```

Works perfectly.

Now I wish to add a separate interface to each object, ISelfPay, and do:

```
  MyDisplayObjects = new List<ISave,ISelfPay> { Patient, ServiceBilling, ReferredBy, POA, PrimaryInsurance, SecondaryInsurance };
```

So that this too will work:

```
foreach (var o in MyDisplayObjects)
{
  o.CanSaveEvent += new EventHandler<CanSaveEventArgs>(CanSaveEventHandler);
  this.SelfPayEvent += new EventHandler<SelfPayEventArgs>(o.CheckInViewModel_SelfPayEvent);
 }
```

> Error: Cannot initialize object of type List <'ISave,ISelfPay'> with a
>   collection initializer.

I can't seem to find much help with Google. How is this done?

(I could make two lists, but I'd like to learn how to do this with one list, if at all possible. :)

TIA

Comment: Only thing I can think of is creating a special interface that all objects share.

Comment: @kevintjuh93 That is exactly what VS is suggesting. :) Thanks.

Comment: Can't u use a dictionary?

Comment: @kevintjuh93 In fact that interface could inherit from both `ISave` and `ISelfPay`. But that pattern becomes cumbersome quickly if more "roles" (interfaces) are added and can be present in different combinations.

Comment: I feel like a `Tuple, Dictionary, KeyValuePair` and or another collection would be better suited.

Comment: @HansPassant How would this work? Thanks.

Comment: @germi I think all objects in one list, and all objects implement both interfaces.

Comment: On a sidenote. Be careful when you register all display objects as event handlers. It means your object holds an additional reference to all display objects. And even if you clear the list, they will not be garbage collected.
This is not a problem, if they have the same lifespan. But otherwise you can create a memory leak

Comment: @treze Great sidenote...Garbage collection remains somewhat of a mystery to me...and trying to pick up memory leaks is hard (for me). :) Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you want your list to be populated by items that are both savable (`ISave`) and self paying (`ISelfPay`)

In order to get compile time safety for this functinality, you would have to define a single interface that includes both of these interfaces.

```
public interface ISaveAndSelfPay : ISelfPay, ISave
{
}

var listOfSavableAndSelfPayableThings = new List<ISaveAndSelfPay>();
```

Comment: @isakSavo I was hoping to use a list with two separate interfaces...but judging from the comments, it must not be possible. :( Thanks.